# configure log4j for each spark job running on yarn mode

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, log4j

I am running spark jobs on yarn client mode. I am running these jobs using spark-submit command inside unix script. I want to have logs for each spark job running.
I tried using below command to get log :

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 2G --jars $spark_jars --class $spark_class  $main_jar |& tee -a ${log_file}
```

but here if spark job gets failed , it will not be caught in command status check , may be unix checks status of |$tee command which is always success whether spark job succeed or fails

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "===========SPARK JOB COMPLETED==================" |& tee -a ${log_file}
else
    echo "===========SPARK JOB FAILED=====================" |& tee -a ${log_file}
fi
```

I tried using log4j but couldn't succeed.
I want to have each spark job log file stored on local unix server.
Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you submit your spark application. It generates an `application_id`. Since this application is running in distributed cluster you can't get logs of spark application with redirection.

However, when you do something like below, it just redirects console logging into a file.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 2G --jars $spark_jars --class $spark_class  $main_jar > ${log_file}
```

To get the logging of the spark application submitted to yarn cluster for example, you need to use yarn logs command:

`yarn logs -applicationId <application ID> [OPTIONS]`

Comment: I ran the job from unix using spark-submit.
I got below issue : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be specified manually.;

however i checked on yarn but couldn't get this exception on yarn, can you please tell me how to see this kind of exceptions on yarn.

Comment: you can grep from the same yarn command...`yarn logs -applicationId <application ID> | grep ERROR`